# Is it safe to get the allocated only bytes form a byte array obtained from GetBuffer?

Tags: c#, .net, mime-message

I have an instance of MemoryStream that is closed (don't ask, can't change that and it is not that poor design as it seems at first glance :).
Anyway I found that I can take the byte[] using something like:

```
MemoryStream ms = SomeClass.GetMemoryStream();
byte[] myData = ms.GetBuffer();
```

Everything seems just great so far, the only problem I have is that the byte array returned from GetBuffer() is resized and contains unallocated space (byte)0; 
Like so:

```
12,32,43,43,2,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

My question is is it safe to assume that I can read the array until I encounter the first 0?
Do you know any case in wich there will be (byte)0 in the middle of the data?
The data is a MIME Email Message.

Comment: Of course memory streams can contain a zero!  Whether yours can depends *entirely* upon the data it contains, and as such this question isn't answerable.

Comment: I will need to upvote your comment as it is true, anyway, as you can see, others proposed methods that actually invalidated my concerns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `ms.ToArray()` : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.toarray.aspx

It works on a closed stream and returns a copy of the data, without the unused part of the buffer.

Comment: Thanks!
My shame I didn't even tried it. I just felt the ToArray() will need to know the Length of the MemoryStream in order to recieve the bytes. It apparently didn't :).
Or maybe it did but since the MemoryStream has private _length field that holds correct even after the stream is closed.

Anyway, thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 3):

The [msdn article on MemoryStream.GetBuffer Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.getbuffer.aspx) says

> Note that the buffer contains allocated bytes which might be unused.
>   For example, if the string "test" is written into the MemoryStream
>   object, the length of the buffer returned from GetBuffer is 256, not
>   4, with 252 bytes unused. To obtain only the data in the buffer, use
>   the ToArray method; however, ToArray creates a copy of the data in
>   memory.

Despite the copy it looks like what you are supposed to do...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, jsobo.
I read the article at msdn, I just moved the ToArray() method away from the puzzle (without even trying it as it felt like it will need the Length property, which I knew threw an exception when the Stream is closed).
As Nicholas Butler suggested to use ToArray() and pointed out that this is going to work with closed stream, I marked his answer while I will upvote yours as it is still helpful.
Thanks!